# How do I find modular multiplicative inverse of number without using division for fpga?

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, rsa, fpga

The canonical answer for this question is "use extended euclidean algorithm" however it utilizes division and multiplication operations, which are pain to implement for very big numbers on FPGAs. I would like to use it in RSA key generation.

Comment: Are you sure there _is_ a less painful way? Generating an RSA key is expected to be an expensive operation.

Comment: You might also look into Montgomery modular multiplication.

Comment: I think, I can't use it since modulus must be odd and .

Comment: RSA modulus is always odd. You can compute the inverse mod phi(n)/4, and use some simple tricks to get the inverse you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend the [binary euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm)

> it replaces division with arithmetic shifts, comparisons, and subtraction

> An extended binary GCD, analogous to the extended Euclidean algorithm, is given by Knuth along with pointers to other versions.

I've found a Python implementation of the binary extended Euclidean algorithm [here](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eucahcjm/combopt/ext_gcd_python_programs.pdf):

```py
def strip_powers_of_two(c, p, q, gamma, delta):
    c = c / 2
    if (p % 2 == 0) and (q % 2 == 0):
        p, q = p//2, q//2
    else:
        p, q = (p + delta)//2, (q - gamma)//2
    return c, p, q

def ext_bin_gcd(a,b):
    u, v, s, t, r = 1, 0, 0, 1, 0
    while (a % 2 == 0) and (b % 2 == 0):
        a, b, r = a//2, b//2, r+1
    alpha, beta = a, b
    while (a % 2 == 0):
        a, u, v = strip_powers_of_two(a, u, v, alpha, beta)
    while a != b:
        if (b % 2 == 0):
            b, s, t = strip_powers_of_two(b, s, t, alpha, beta)
        elif b < a:
            a, b, u, v, s, t = b, a, s, t, u, v
        else:
            b, s, t = b - a, s - u, t - v
    return (2 ** r) * a, s, t
```

Answer (score 2):

Given `n`, let `Φ(n)` be the number of integers less than `n` and relatively prime to it.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem, if `m` is relatively prime to `n` then `m^(Φ(n)-1)` is the multiplicative inverse of `m`.  This can be computed with `O(log(n))` multiplications.

Comment: There is one issue with this solution. It requires computing `m^(phi(n)-1)` modulo MOD, so it involves finding the remainder and uses division, anyway.

Comment: Good answer for the use case -- would normally only apply for constant moduli where you can precompute Φ(n), but since this is for RSA key generation, Φ(n) can be easily calculated from the factors of n, which are known.

Comment: @kraskevich I don't think that's the Φ(n) I'm looking for. In private key generation one must find d ≡ e^(−1) (mod φ(n)), so my φ(n) is in fact e^((φ(φ(n))-1) mod φ(n). Also since φ(n) equals (p-1)(q-1) and both of them are primes, I can't use my Montgomery fast exponentiation core because it works only when modulus is odd.